# Can you preserve whitespace in empty elements with minimized tag syntax?

Tags: xml, parsing, vba, whitespace

XML looks like this *(so with a space after 'ComputerName')*

```
<XML><Data><ComputerName /><UserName>Me</UserName></Data></XML>
```

code like this

```
Set l_objDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
l_objDom.preserveWhiteSpace = True
Call l_objDom.loadXML("<XML><Data><ComputerName /><UserName>Me</UserName></Data></XML>")
Set l_objNode = l_objDom.SelectSingleNode("XML/Data")
Debug.Print l_objNode.XML
```

returns

```
<Data><ComputerName/><UserName>Me</UserName></Data>
```

how to preserve the space?
because we perform a checksum (CRC32) over the xml of the `<Data>` tag, which is now mismatching.

the **preserveWhiteSpace** property seems to be ignored or not working...

Answer (score -1):

That is not proper.
i.e. XML nodes can't have space(s) in it

> XML elements must follow these naming
>   rules:
>
> ```
> Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
> Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
> Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
> Names cannot contain spaces
> ```

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: i don't think it's that clear, see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/empty.html

Comment: This is not true: [the W3C recommendation allows a space between the element name and the slash](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-EmptyElemTag).

Comment: First of w3schools is not official documentation and is quite often wrong. Secondly your reference doesn't even support your claim - yes the *names* can't have spaces in them - because adding a space would separate it into a name and an attribute. That doesn't say anything about whether you can have a space in the tag, just that it isn't part of the tag name.